# How to join type and mpl::vector into a new vector

Tags: c++, boost, c++11, boost-mpl

I use the following construct to create a mpl vector of types.

```
struct Struct1{
    typedef int type;
};
struct Struct2{
    typedef float type;
};
template<typename T> struct TypeReader{
    typedef typename T::type type;
};

int main()
{
    typedef bm::vector<Struct1,Struct2> MPLVector;
    typedef bm::transform<MPLVector, TypeReader<bm::_1>>::type TypeList;
    static_assert(bm::equal<TypeList, bm::vector<int,float> >::value, "Is not same");
}
```

So far this works as expected. Now what I would like to do is the following

```
struct Struct3{
    typedef bm::vector<char,double> type;
};
typedef bm::vector<Struct1,Struct2,Struct3> MPLVector;
typedef bm::transform<MPLVector, TypeReader<bm::_1>>::type TypeList;
static_assert(bm::equal<TypeList, bm::vector<int,float,char,double> >::value, "Is not same");
```

This does not work. So how do I need to change my MetaFunction struct that it will work with both, just a typedef and a mpl::vector?
Or if this is not possible would it be possible to do this if I change all type typedefs to mpl vectors?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think this is possible with `mpl::transform`, since it would need to generate several elements in the resulting sequence from a single one in the source sequence. However, this can be done with [`mpl::fold`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_47_0/libs/mpl/doc/refmanual/fold.html), along with specialization with [`mpl::is_sequence`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_47_0/libs/mpl/doc/refmanual/is-sequence.html):

```
// Default case
template < typename Seq, typename TWrapper, typename Enable = void >
struct Flatten_imp
    : mpl::push_back< Seq, typename TWrapper::type >
{
};

// Sequence case
template < typename Seq, typename TWrapper >
struct Flatten_imp< 
    Seq,
    TWrapper, typename
    boost::enable_if< 
        mpl::is_sequence< typename 
            TWrapper::type 
        > 
    >::type
>   
{
    typedef mpl::joint_view< 
        Seq, typename 
        TWrapper::type 
    > type;
};

template < typename Seq >
struct Flatten
    : mpl::fold< Seq, mpl::vector<>, Flatten_imp< mpl::_, mpl::_ > >
{}

int main()
{
    typedef mpl::vector< Struct1, Struct2, Struct3 > MPLVector;
    typedef Flatten< MPLVector >::type TypeList;

    static_assert(
        mpl::equal<
            TypeList, 
            mpl::vector< int, float, char, double > 
        >::value, "Is not same");
}
```

If you want the flattening to be recursive, you can call `Flatten` in `Flatten_impl` to flatten the sequence before appending it; however, be careful that this recursion will only work if your sequences contain wrappers and not direct types, e.g.

```
struct Struct3
{
    typedef mpl::vector< mpl::identity< char >, mpl::identity< double > > type;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the complete answer. Fold never came to my mind, but your solution is really nice.

Comment: Nice answer. I didn't know about `is_sequence`.

Answer (score 0):

You'd have to specialize `TypeReader` for the case where the parameter is a Sequence (mpl vector, fusion list/vector/tuple);

In that case combine the power of **[`mpl::back_inserter`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_46_1/libs/mpl/doc/refmanual/back-inserter.html)** with **[`mpl::copy`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_46_1/libs/mpl/doc/refmanual/copy.html)** (to copy from the parameter's Sequence into the target type)

I don't currently have to time to demo this. For hints on how to specialize for the *concept* of a Sequence, you could look at `boost::enable_if`. However, a ProofOfConcept could easily be done by just specializing on `template <typename> mpl::vector`

Comment: Specializing `TypeReader` sounds easier than it actually is.

Comment: @pmr: I was editing hint in already. I know, but I can't do the PoC right now